# How to use custom source model in eav_attribute

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

Ho can I use a custom source in the source_model of the eav_attribute table?
Thats my source

```
* 
* @category  Mcas
* @package   Mcas_Industries
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2019
* @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
*/
namespace Mcas\Industries\Source;

class Industry implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
/**
 * Industry repository
 * 
 * @var \Mcas\Industries\Api\IndustryRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $industryRepository;

/**
 * Search Criteria Builder
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
 */
protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * Filter Builder
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
 */
protected $filterBuilder;

/**
 * Options
 * 
 * @var array
 */
protected $options;

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param \Mcas\Industries\Api\IndustryRepositoryInterface $industryRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    \Mcas\Industries\Api\IndustryRepositoryInterface $industryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
) {
    $this->industryRepository    = $industryRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder         = $filterBuilder;
}

/**
 * Retrieve all Industries as an option array
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws StateException
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (empty($this->options)) {
        $options = [];
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $searchResults = $this->industryRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $industry) {
            $options[] = [
                'value' => $industry->getIndustryId(),
                'label' => $industry->getIndustry(),
            ];
        }
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    return $this->options;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return $this->getAllOptions();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Source Model When You Create Attribute

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
               \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
           'international',
           [
               'group' => 'General',
               'type' => 'int',
               'label' => 'International',
               'backend' => '',
               'input' => 'select',
               'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
               'source' => 'Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\YesNo',
               'required' => true,
               'sort_order' => 15,
               'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
               'used_in_product_listing' => false,
               'visible_on_front' => false,
       ]
   );
```

Comment: I created a dropdown attribute in the admin, then I have replaced the source_model value on the eav_atttribute table. In the past it has worked, but now I get a blank page. I dont understand why.

Comment: i think the attribute can not get any options

Comment: I dont understand why it doesnt work. In 'eav_attribute', there are 'backend_model' and 'source_model'. Backend_model is empty, in 'source_model' I have placed my source 'Mcas\Industries\Source\Industry'. In my custom modules it is working, but when I call the 'product edit page' I get a blank screen